# Xamarin.forms Tabbed Page not showing in ios after PopAsync()

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a xamarin.forms application which have a login screen and TabbedsPage as MainPage. 
The navigation from login page to MainPage is like

```
     Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new MainPage(), this);
     await Navigation.PopAsync();
```

The problem I am facing is that Tabbed Page not showing in ios. It works fine in android. What will be the issue?

Comment: Why you are using PopAsync()?

Comment: @KK bro because I dont want to open login page after backpress from mainpage.

Comment: it would be much simpler to just assign Application.Current.MainPage

Comment: @Jason bro can you explain?

Comment: after login, re-assign the MainPage; `Application.Current.MainPage = new MainPage();`  This will replace LoginPage with MainPage

Comment: @Jason This solved the issue. But after done the solution suggested by you another one arised, The top navigation now not showing, I have set  NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false); in login page. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it would be much simpler to just assign the app's `MainPage`

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new MainPage();
```

This will replace `LoginPage` with `MainPage`.  If you need Navigation, then wrap it in a `NavigationPage`

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
```